# How detect user browser only for uc-mini & opera-mini

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wants a script that detect user browser if only when user browser is uc-mini & opera-mini .These type of browser doen't support **transition**  .

So when detect this browser then disable the **transition**  property and add `display:none` property.

Comment: Instead of using user-agent based detection, can't you simply use Modernizr.js to detect of CSS transitions are supported? UA detection is often unreliable. Feature detection, however, is.

Comment: No, this question is not a duplicate, since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089868/javascript-how-to-detect-if-the-user-is-using-uc-browser-mini doesn't explain how to detect Opera Mini, which is half of what the OP was asking. However, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653217/opera-mini-browser-detection-using-javascript does answer that part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either use the plugin [checkit.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Easy-Browser-Device-Feature-Detection-Plugin-For-jQuery-checkit-js.html) or this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40433933/3312323)