# Javascript: How to detect UC Browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-agent, uc-browser

I am creating website, in which I want to know user if user is using UC Browser or not?

`I tried the solution suggest in` **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089868/javascript-how-to-detect-if-the-user-is-using-uc-browser-mini/40433933#40433933)**, `but it's not working`. So I print userAgent and in UC it is something like this

[image]

So I used `navigator.userAgent.match(/UCBrowser/i)` for decting UC.

Is it good way or there any better way to detect UC?

Thanks.

Comment: that will be the most used way

Comment: Yes it is, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript