# Detect Data saving mode in opera mini

Tags: javascript, opera, opera-mini

I have developed a site which works on all browsers except opera mini.  It works on opera mini only if user disables "Data Saving Mode".When my site loads in the browser, I want to check the status of "Data Saving Mode". If it is "on" i can show the popup and ask the user to disable Data Saving mode.

Is it possible to check if Data Saving Mode enabled or not with javascript?

Comment: Did you have looked in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653217/opera-mini-browser-detection-using-javascript) ? I'm not sure if Opera mini's browser API offers a mean to check that option.

Comment: @KarelG this question is asking about browser detection. And I am asking about the data saving mode.

Comment: It may be case when user disable the data saving , on the second visit also he will get the same popup